# Insert null in Sqlite table

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to figure how to insert a null value into an SQLite table in Android.

This is the table:

```
"create table my table (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                                               "deviceAddress   text not null unique, " +
                                               "lookUpKey text , " + 
                                               "deviceName text , " +
                                               "contactName text , " +
                                               "playerName text , " +
                                               "playerPhoto blob " +
                                               ");";
```

I wanted to use a simple Insert command via `execSQL` but since one of the values is a blob I can't do it (I think).

So, I am using a standard `db.Insert` command.
How do I make one of the values null?

If I just skip it in the `ContentValues` object will it automatically put a null value in the column?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, you can skip the field in ContentValues and db.insert will set it NULL.
Also you can use the other way:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.putNull("column1");
db.insert("table1", null, cv);
```

this directrly sets "column1" NULL. Also you can use this way in update statement.

Comment: you can't send null to put method, instead you must use putNull method

Comment: Actually the answer is not wrong. When you checked the source code of the ContentValues.java which is located at the android.content package, it can be seen that; the method simply calls put method with a supplied null argument. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/content/ContentValues.java#ContentValues.putNull%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: **public void putNull(String key) { mValues.put(key, null); }**  ... I suppose putNull's implementation could change, so it is probably better   to use it rather than put directly. Nonetheless, it's still a correct answer.

Comment: @Samus Arin I think *putNull(String key)* is a convenience method to set a Column value to null and it's implementation shouldn't change.

Comment: For me, when I tried to skip a date field, even though the field was not required to be `NOT NULL`, I had issues trying to do inserts using C# into SQLite, giving an error that `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`.  Maybe Android code is different.  But I had to insert `null` in my `INSERT` command string, instead.

Answer (score 81):

You can use [ContentValues.putNull(String key)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html#putNull%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can skip it but you can also put null, just make sure that when you first create the Database, you don't declare the column as "NOT NULL".

Comment: For me, when I tried to skip a date field, even though the field was not required to be `NOT NULL`, I had issues trying to do inserts using C# into SQLite, giving an error that `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`.  Maybe Android code is different.  But I had to insert `null` in my `INSERT` command string, instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your insert query string command, you can insert `null` for the value you want to be null.  This is C# as I don't know how you set up database connections for Android, but the query would be the same, so I've given it for illustrative purposes I'm sure you could equate to your own:

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(SQLiteConnString()); 
// where SQLiteConnString() is a function that returns this string with the path of the SQLite DB file:
// String.Format("Data Source={0};Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;", filePath);

try 
{
    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable (SomeColumn) VALUES (null)";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // do something with ex.ToString() or ex.Message
}
```