# how to allow save null image in database?

Tags: android

now finally i set my code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910206/sqlite-database-works-in-emulator-but-not-in-real-device every thing is fine but only problem is if i donot upload any image and press Save button application stop unexpectedly what do i do?so is allow to save information without image?? i want to save values without image in database and when i press edit is browse and upload  image how i do that??

Comment: is your image column nullable? (i.e. will it accept null values via your table's DDL?)

Comment: u mean i write in table like this  image BLOB nullable??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try...(something like)

```
    create table MY_TABLE (
        _id integer primary key autoincrement,
        my_image blob, 
        ...
    )
```

where the image column is able to take NULL as a value. if you define it as `my_image blob not null` then you MUST give it a "real" value (non-null).

Comment: i already did like this      String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE country (_id integer primary key autoincrement,name text,cap text,code text,Location text,Notes text,Person text,Image BLOB );";

Comment: the only column that is NULL when you hit the <SAVE> button is the image?

Comment: i see you let all columns (except the primary key) be nullable. how are you handling the `?` placeholders when you have no value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823514/insert-null-in-sqlite-table should help answer this as well.

Comment: yes i didnot press brose and upload image just click o n save

Comment: can you show me your INSERT statement? how do you handle (programatically) the missing (i.e. null) values?

Comment: DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

       if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
       {
        dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
          capEt.getText().toString(),
          codeEt.getText().toString(),
          Donedate.getText().toString(),
          Notes.getText().toString(),
          Person.getText().toString()
          ,blob
          
          
          
          
          );
       }
       else

Comment: see thi article my full soure is here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910206/sqlite-database-works-in-emulator-but-not-in-real-device

Comment: that article didn't take into account nullable columns in a table. clearly if `nameEt` doesn't have a value, then it's `toString()` will not do what you hope it will do. you have all columns (except _id) nullable...1/2 way there. you need to interrogate each column for a value...if it has one then the `toString()` makes sense. if it doesn't then you need to insert `null` (not as a String!). check out the reference i posted  "insert-null-in-sqlite-table" for more info.

Comment: where is refrence tell me please  insert-null-in-sqlite-table

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823514/insert-null-in-sqlite-table good luck!!

Comment: public void insertContact(String name, String cap, String code, String LocationEd, String Notes, String Person,byte[] blob) 
      {
         ContentValues newCon = new ContentValues();
         newCon.put("name", name);
         newCon.put("cap", cap);
         newCon.put("code", code);
         
         newCon.put("Location",LocationEd);
         newCon.put("Notes",Notes);
         newCon.put("Person",Person);
         newCon.put("Image", blob);

         open();
         database.insert("country", null, newCon);
         close();
      }

Comment: according to "insert-null-in-sqlite-table" you will need to verify whether or not you have actual values for `newCon`. use those values where present, and `putNull()` where missing.

Comment: basically `null` is a special case that is not the String value "null". it is indicative of NO VALUE PRESENT.

Comment: @HayyaAnam : try to insert `NULL` or "" if you have no image to insert

Comment: no i want to upload defualt icon image if i donot browse any image from gellry show fedault/drawbale/ic_launcher.png image