# Inserting data into a db from a list

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I have a problem inserting data from a list into a db SQLite. Some element of the list are null and then when i'm going to take this element i see a null pointer exception. What i can do to store in db this data even though some are null??

This is the code:

```
private void insertDB() {
    for(int i = 0; i < listA.size(); i++) {
        int check = dbPF.createPF(listA.get(i).getA(), listA.get(i).getB(), listA.get(i).getC(), listA.get(i).getD());
    }
 }

public int createPF(int a, String b, String c, String d) {
    ContentValues initialValues = createContentValuesPF(a, b, c, d);
    return (int) database.insert(tableA, null, initialValues);
}

private ContentValues creaContentValuesPod(int a, String b, String c, String d) {
       ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
       values.put(key1, a);
       values.put(key2, b);
       values.put(key3, c);
       values.put(key4, d);
       return values;
}
```

Eclipse return a NullPointerException when one of the node of the list is null, but i want to store in db also null values. What i can do?

Thanks to all

Comment: eck first if your list.get(i) isn't null before call the gets, get, getC

Comment: ok but i want that in db is stored null when data is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a list item is `null`, you cannot call `getA()` etc.

You need to do something else when you have a `null` item:

```
private void insertDB() {
    for(int i = 0; i < listA.size(); i++) {
        int check = dbPF.createPF(listA.get(i));
    }
}

public int createPF(MyObject item) {
    ContentValues initialValues = createContentValuesPF(item);
    return (int) database.insert(tableA, null, initialValues);
}

private ContentValues creaContentValuesPod(MyObject item) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    if (item != null) {
        values.put(key1, item.getA());
        values.put(key2, item.getB());
        values.put(key3, item.getC());
        values.put(key4, item.getD());
    } else {
        values.putNull(key1); // or whatever value(s) you want
    }
    return values;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure in your table creation statment doesn't have "not null" in it. 
When using the ContentValues just skip the fields you want to be null.

Check out this question. It will give you what you want. [Insert Nulls in SQLite DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823514/insert-null-in-sqlite-table)

Comment: hi! my db hasn't not null clause. My problem is when i take data from the listA, because some attributes can be null

Comment: Check your data to see if it’s null before you try to insert it then. If you don’t add the value to the contentValues, Android will automatically set it to null in your db. 
if(a != null){
  values.put(key1, a);
}
if(b != null){
       values.put(key2, b);
}
if(b != null){
       values.put(key3, c);
}

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a PreparedStatement you can insert null data to the database by leveraging the setNull API. Below is an example

```
            preparedStatement.setNull(parameterIndex,Types.DATE);
```

Comment: i'm using a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper to create my db. With the oncreate method i can execSQL(query) to create

Answer (score 0):

Check if its null and than put nulls into the DB.

```java
private void insertDB() {
    String a = "";
    String b = "";
    String c = "";
    String d = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < listA.size(); i++) {
        if(listA.get(i) != null){
            a = listA.get(i).getA();
            b = listA.get(i).getB();
            c = listA.get(i).getC();
            d = listA.get(i).getD();   
        }
        int check = dbPF.createPF(a, b, c, d);
    }
 }

private ContentValues creaContentValuesPod(int a, String b, String c, String d) {
   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
   values.put(key1, a);

   if(b.equals(""){
      values.put(key2, null);
   }else{
      values.put(key2, b);
   }
   if(c.equals(""){
      values.put(key3, null);
   }else{
      values.put(key3, c);
   }
   if(d.equals(""){
      values.put(key4, null);
   }else{
      values.put(key4, d);
   }
   return values;
```

}

I put an empty string.
I have a question, why you have in a list Null-pointer-reference? It's not a good methodology.

Comment: I create my db here: 'create table Tab1(A integer primary key autoincrement, B text, C text, D text)'      the db has 15 columns and than some of this can be null for some rows but i don't want write an empty string

Comment: an empty string is equals null? Because the get(i) is not null, but can be null the getA() or the getB() or the getC() or the getD()

Comment: Try it OR use instead String a = ""; this String a = "null"; 
Try and see what is in your DB.

Comment: when i'm going to select * from tabA i can see the rows with "" or "null" :(

Comment: ok, but i don't check if getA() getB() getC() and getD() is null. If i want to do this i had to put an if inside the "for" for each get and i have 15 columns. If the problem is for example here: b = listA.get(i).getB(); i can't check if getB() is null because i check if get(i) is null

Comment: Or you can do it in a upper level. If A B C D and so on is null than you put instead of null a empty string like "". Than you can only have to create 15 if-condition in creaContentValuesPod like i do it and the for loop will be clean.